# How to not call a function when returning from another fragment Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation

I have a fragment which contains a RecyclerView. In this fragment I make a call to get data from an API and then display the data into recyclerview. I call the method to get the data in onViewCreated method. When I click on an item from the list, a Map Fragment is opened and display the location of that item. Now when I press the back button I dont want the method to get data to be called again. Any suggestions on how can I do that? Maybe it's a simple solution but I can't figured it out.  Thanks

**ListFragment:**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val backBtn: AppCompatImageView = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.back_btn)
    backBtn.visibility = View.GONE
   

    binding.swipeRefreshMeteors.setOnRefreshListener {
        binding.swipeRefreshMeteors.isRefreshing = false
        getMeteorsDetails()
    }

    getMeteorsDetails()
    observeIsLoading()
    observeMeteorsData()
}

private fun getMeteorsDetails(){
    meteorsViewmodel.getMeteorsData()
}
```

**MapFragment**

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val backBtn: AppCompatImageView = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.back_btn)
    backBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    backBtn.setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigateUp()
    }

    val meteorName = arguments?.getString("meteor_name")
    val meteorLat = arguments?.getString("meteor_lat")
    val meteorLong = arguments?.getString("meteor_long")
    val meteorFallenYear = arguments?.getString("meteor_fallen_year")
    supportMapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.google_map) as SupportMapFragment

    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync { googleMap ->
        val meteorLocation = LatLng(meteorLat!!.toDouble(), meteorLong!!.toDouble())
        googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(meteorLocation).title(meteorName).snippet(
                    "Year: $meteorFallenYear"
        ).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)))!!.showInfoWindow()
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(meteorLocation, 10f))
        //googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(meteorLocation, 10f))
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
 val getMeteorsResponse: LiveData<Resource<ArrayList<MeteorModel>>?>
    get() = _getMeteorsResponse
private val _getMeteorsResponse = MutableLiveData<Resource<ArrayList<MeteorModel>>?>()

val isLoading: LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = _isLoading
private val _isLoading = MutableLiveData(false)

fun getMeteorsData(){
    _isLoading.value = true
    disposable.add(
        meteorsRepository.getMeteors()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<ArrayList<MeteorModel>>(){
                override fun onSuccess(response : ArrayList<MeteorModel>) {
                    _isLoading.value = false
                    _getMeteorsResponse.value = Resource.success(response)
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    _isLoading.value = false
                    _getMeteorsResponse.value = Resource.error(e.message ?: "Error", null)
                    Log.e(TAG, e.message.toString())
                }

            })
    )
}

fun resetMeteors(){
        _getMeteorsResponse.value = null
}
```

Comment: Use a `ViewModel` and make the API call inside the `init` of the `ViewModel`.

Comment: I'm using a Viewmodel, I'm updating the question with the viewmodel code, can you please take a look and give me an example? Thanks

Comment: There is no point in me explaining it to you. Read [this](https://proandroiddev.com/5-common-mistakes-when-using-architecture-components-403e9899f4cb#89fe)